# Internal server error 500 between Angularjs and api

Tags: angularjs, api

I am trying to save data from angularjs sending it to an api but i have the error 500 internal server error. the controller is an array hols the scops coming from the html page.
any help

Controller

```
$scope.save = function ()
{
    $scope.setup.push({
        "Spec_Code": $scope.spec, "Medical_CTG": $scope.deg, "Doctor_Code": $scope.st, "Main_Serv": $scope.stypecode, "Serv_Group": $scope.sgroupcode, "Sub_Serv": $scope.sub,
        "Pat_Type": $scope.patype, "Calc_Type": $scope.calcs, "Calc_From": $scope.rfrom, "Calc_Val": $scope.calcvalue, "STAFF_TYPE": $scope.stafftype,
        "pricelist": $scope.selectedpricelist
    })


    var promisePost = Doctorssetup.save($scope.setup);
    promisePost.then(function (pl) {
    }, function (err) {
        console.log("Err" + err);
    });
    console.log($scope.setup);
}


    var promisePost = Doctorssetup.save($scope.setup);
    promisePost.then(function (pl) {
    }, function (err) {
        console.log("Err" + err);
    });
    console.log($scope.setup);
}
```

api

```
public HttpResponseMessage save ([FromBody]Doctorssetup setup)
    {
        obj.ExecNonQuery(string.Format("insert into Doctor_Cont_Det (Spec_Code,Medical_CTG,Doctor_Code,Main_Serv,Serv_Group,Sub_Serv, Pat_Type,Calc_Type,Calc_From,Calc_Val,Sys_Date,STAFF_TYPE,pricelist) values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}','{12}')"
            , setup.Spec_Code
            , setup.Medical_CTG
            , setup.Doctor_Code
            , setup.Main_Serv
            , setup.Serv_Group
            , setup.Sub_Serv
            , setup.Pat_Type
            , setup.Calc_Type
            , setup.Calc_From
            , setup.Calc_Val
            , DateTime.Now
            , setup.STAFF_TYPE
            , setup.pricelist
            ));
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        return response;
    }
```

thanks lot

Comment: Please, please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement. Your 500 probably comes  with an error message and stack trace. Read it too.

Comment: Open your browser deverloper tool, network tab - what is the HTTP request angular sends (Method ? Body ? ) and what is the response (body of the response)

Answer (score 1):

Your function on the controller expects an object, but you are trying to post an array. Change it as follows,

```
$scope.setup = {
        "Spec_Code": $scope.spec, "Medical_CTG": $scope.deg, "Doctor_Code": $scope.st, "Main_Serv": $scope.stypecode, "Serv_Group": $scope.sgroupcode, "Sub_Serv": $scope.sub,
        "Pat_Type": $scope.patype, "Calc_Type": $scope.calcs, "Calc_From": $scope.rfrom, "Calc_Val": $scope.calcvalue, "STAFF_TYPE": $scope.stafftype,
        "pricelist": $scope.selectedpricelist
    });
```

also convert to string before posting it using **`JSON.stringify($scope.setup);`**