# If the content type is json, data is not going to WebAPI Post action in Angular using Visual Studio IDE

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I'm using **Visual Studio IDE** for doing Angular2 project. Now the problem is, if the content-type is json, below code does't able to call WebAPI Post Action. Whereas, If the content-type is **x-www-form-urlencoded**, then able to call post action. But the data in WebAPI Post action parameter is null as shown here in image.

```
postEmployee(emp: Employee) {
    var body = JSON.stringify(emp);
    var headerOptions = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
    var requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ method: RequestMethod.Post, headers: headerOptions });
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:64925/api/Employee/PostEmployee', body, requestOptions).map(x => x.json());
}
```

after posting the data, which is null showing below..
[image]

So, for this problem I want to send json data from client side. But, if the content-type is json like below, it is not going to Post action method of WebAPI

```
postEmployee(emp: Employee) {
    var body = JSON.stringify(emp);
    var headerOptions = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    var requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ method: RequestMethod.Post, headers: headerOptions });
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:64925/api/Employee/PostEmployee', body, requestOptions).map(x => x.json());
}
```

**Web.config** is

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     <!--<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />-->
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods"
         value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Any one knows the solution for the above stated problem in **Visual Studio IDE**..?Thanks in Advance..
[Demo Project link from you tube](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Angular+4+CRUD+With+Web+API&dcr=0&source=lnms&tbm=vid&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwis0oelj_DYAhVCF5QKHfS5ABIQ_AUICigB&biw=1264&bih=871). In this project, they are using Visual Studio Code..But I need to use same code in Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: post your interface

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137849/internal-server-error-500-between-angularjs-and-api

Comment: Model class *employee.model.ts* is                                                   export class Employee {
    EmployeeID: number;
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    EmpCode: string;
    Position: string;
    Office: string;
}

Comment: I'm using Angular2/4 and provided more information regarding demo project @Sajeetharan

Comment: Below posted the problem I got and Answer..Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to absence of below line

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute(origins:"*", headers: "*", methods: "*"));
```

in **WebApiConfig.cs** of WebAPI Project..Along with you should install **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors** for the WebAPI project.

*WebApiConfig.cs*

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute(origins:"*", headers: "*", methods: "*"));
        //config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*"));

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "Get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `[From Body]` attribute for `Employee` in your action:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostEmployee([FromBody] Employee)
```

from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api):

> When a parameter has [FromBody], Web API uses the Content-Type header to select a formatter.

Comment: Used your suggestion. But No improvement..Thanks for support

Comment: It's weird, Have you tried using postman and fiddler? In order to find out where the problem is exacty?

Answer (score 1):

Reference : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ous6v0r7kXc,
try after removing httpProtocol From WebConfig

Comment: But, I need the same using Visual Studio IDE @Shamseer K Smr..Your suggestion works only for Visual Studio Code Editor. For doing angular2/4 project in Visual Studio IDE, you can refer this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWQZCDegWHg&list=PL6n9fhu94yhWqGD8BuKuX-VTKqlNBj-m6&pbjreload=10

Comment: Below posted the problem I got and Answer..Thanks Sir