# Controller not receiving data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
vm.MostrarDiv = function() {

  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: _obterUrlAPI() + "ImportacaoPreFatura/ValidarLayoutTeste",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    params: {
      listaTeste: vm.carregarLayoutTeste
    }
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    vm.preFatura = response.data;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    MessageBox("Erro", response.data.Message);
  });
};
```

The param, vm.carregarLayoutTeste has values, but when it reach the controller.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("ValidarLayoutTeste")]

public IHttpActionResult ValidarLayoutTeste(List<ValidaLayout> listaTeste) {
```

The listaTeste comes as `null`, does somebody knows why this is happening?

Comment: What is the expected value of `vm.carregarLayoutTeste`? It's probably just not being assigned a value properly

Answer (score 0):

Try with JSON.stringify your data

```
params: {
 listaTeste: JSON.stringify(vm.carregarLayoutTeste)
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, the listTeste is still null in the controller.

Comment: try the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137849/internal-server-error-500-between-angularjs-and-api

Comment: What happens, say, if you just send the number '5'. Does it still get null? This will help further debugging

Comment: I tried to send the number 5 and it went right. maybe its the type of the object?

Comment: I think the problem is that i'm sending a array and it expects a object, but i dont know how to change.

Comment: You can check type of data which is sent to bakend, i.e. if expect int than should from frontend send 0 not "0", just say to check, I had a same problem.